# How to get form data into laravel 5.6 controller that posted with OPTIONS method

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

I am creating APIs into laravel 5.6 for angular.
Form data is sending to API with OPTIONS method.
How can I get this data into the controller?

I have tested like this.

jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({         
  url:'domain.com/laravel_app/api/register_user',
    type:"options",
    dataType:'json',
    data:{name:'Joe'},
    success:function(r)
    {
        console.log(r);
    }
  })
```

Laravel route

```
Route::match(['post', 'options'], '/register_user/', 'UserController@register_user');
```

Laravel controller

```
public function register_user(Request $request)
{
    print_r($request->all());

    $arr1['status']='SUCCESS';
    return json_encode($arr1);

}
```

All is working fine with "post" method but not with "options"

Comment: just add this in your routes file `Route::options('{all}', function () {
    $response = Response::make('');
    return $response;
});`

Comment: Not working in my case. How can I get value of requested "name" field?

Comment: requested name field ? `Route::options('{all}'` routes means it return empty success response for any routes with `options` method. when you call ajax the options method for that url is called before to get CORS information

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an issue with jQuery ignoring [the spec on the OPTIONS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS) verb and sending your data as the request body.

You should be able to bypass this by doing:

```
$.ajax({         
  url:'domain.com/laravel_app/api/register_user?'+$.param({name: 'Joe'}),
    type:"options",
    dataType:'json',
    success:function(r)
    {
        console.log(r);
    }
  })
```

However keep in mind that according to [the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/OPTIONS):

> The HTTP OPTIONS method is used to describe the communication options for the target resource.

What you are using this request here does not seem to be used to describe **communication  options for the target resource** so you should not be using the OPTIONS method for this.